# log4net doesnt work when project is set to Release build

Tags: .net, log4net

When I build my project in Debug mode log4net works, so the log file is created and written to as expected.  However, when I build my project in Release mode, and copy files to production server, log4net does not create the log file or write to it.

If I copy files using Debug mode log4net works in production server.

I enabled internal debugging.  When running in Release mode the internal log files shows:

> log4net: Assembly [WebAPI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.

webconfig file:

```
  <log4net debug="true">   
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="File" value="webapi.log" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />      
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">  
      <listeners>
        <add
          name="textWriterTraceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="appTrace.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

How do I get log4net working when building in Release mode?

Comment: Does a release build work locally?

Comment: how do u bootstrap log4net config file? are u using assemblyattribute or explicit config load?

Comment: I have following in my Startup.cs file:  [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]

Comment: Release build does not work locally either.

Comment: Try adding [assembly: RepositoryAttribute("Your.Namespace.Here")] to AssemblyInfo.cs in WebAPI project.

Comment: @Raj - please add your comment as a response, so I can accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding [assembly: RepositoryAttribute("Your.Namespace.Here")] to AssemblyInfo.cs in WebAPI project.

Comment: Could you please clarify what this does exactly? I have a windows service which references a library. The log info calls from the library don't log anything. The library has a different namespace than the windows service. Can I specify multiple RepositoryAttribute entries?

Comment: I don't understand why the debug version works differently.

Comment: Just to be clear the library used by the windows service is also mine